# обновление проекта c#

Tags: c#, winforms, обновление, клиент

Столкнулся с такой задачей по обновлению клиента приложения.

```
private void GetProductVersion()
        {
            int currentVersion = Convert.ToInt32(Application.ProductVersion.Replace(".", ""));
            int versionRemote = 0;
            string queryProductVersion = String.Format("select \"file_ver\" from dbo.AutoUpdates where \"module_name\" = 'KDocMessage'");
            var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
            string connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}", loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.UserId, loadData.PWD);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryProductVersion, conn))
                {
                    versionRemote = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(".", ""));
                }
            }
        }
```

После идет сравнение версий, и если не совпадают то нужно скачать обновление и перезапустить клиент.
В нете в основном инфа про WebClient, нужно чтобы обновляло с ftp сервера(на ПК), там лежит папка с "свежими" файлами. Может кто поделится полезной ссылочкой.

Я так понимаю должно осуществляться это через `Directory`? Нужен ли для этого второй exe-шник?

При нажатии на публикацию просит ввести адрес папки-установки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда выбираю папку, выдает такую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы слышали про ClickOnce? Вероятно Вы захотите переложить на него эту задачу: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019

Comment: А так да, есть две старые классические схемы: 1. В качестве запуска программы запускать модуль проверки обновлений, который обновит и запустит основной клиент. 2. Запускать основной клиент, который проверит версию модуля обновления и обновит его, затем проверит свою версию и запустит модуль обновления, который обновит основной клиент и после обновления запустит его снова. Обновление библиотек можно тоже реализовать по-разному...

Comment: @OlegGranRCM я так понимаю ClickOnce происходит автоматически при запуске приложение, настройки все происходят в свойствах проекта?

Comment: да, настройки делаются в свойствах проекта, но проверить наличие обновлений можно и из кода.

Comment: @OlegGranRCM не совсем понятно по поводу настройки обновлений, когда выбираю, допустим, перед входом в программу, нужно еще указывать место обновления (путь к нему), при выборе папки выдает ошибку. И как оно  в целом должно работать, делаем публикацию с указанной версией и при запуске приложения, если его версия отличается от версии публикации происходит обновление?

Comment: Что за ошибка? Да

Comment: Путь к публикации должен быть URL или UNC путем в вашем случае это \\localhost\d$\Project Visual Studio\Новая папка

Comment: @OlegGranRCM вроде разобрался, еще вопрос, я в настройках указал чтобы обновления проверялись перед запуском приложения, вроде как проверяет но не обновляет, обновляет только если запустить не через панель "Пуск", а через `FirstApp.application`, почему так, разве не должно оно автоматом перед запуском обновляться если есть изменения? И можно как-то сделать чтобы после обновления не слетали настройки приложения (в моем случае теряется соединение с базой данных), а чтобы оставалось все как и до обновления?

Comment: В "Пуск" не само приложение, а прослойка ClickOnce он как раз и занимается проверкой и обновлением. При обновлении приложение полностью перезапускается и все соединения обрубаются. Вы можете их при запуске восстанавливать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент, кмк, самый удобный способ это использовать [ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2019).

1. Необходимо указать путь по которому будет опубликовано приложение. Путь к публикации должен быть вида URL или UNC например \Server\SharedFolder\Folder\File или http://server/folder

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Указать версию публикации, именно это значение в дальнейшем ClickOnce будет сравнивать со значением версии приложения на клиенте.
3. В параметрах обновления можно указать будет ли клиент проверять обновление автоматически или это будет сделано приложением самостоятельно, или ниже какой версии не давать запускать приложение и обновлять автоматически без запроса к пользователю нужно ли обновить. Можно настроить ряд других стратегий обновлений о которых можно почитать на MSDN.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. После введения всех параметров, нажать кнопку опубликовать, либо воспользоваться мастером публикации.
5. Установить приложение из места публикации.

Comment: вроде все так делаю, в главном вопросе редактировал, с чем у меня проблема